# Differing PSQL Planners with same Indexes

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

I have been trying to speed up my psql queries to squeeze out as much speed as possible. With a few indexes I installed on my local system I got good speeds. I installed these on the remote system but had different results. The screenshot for the planners follow:

Local Planner:

```
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=19.54..67.37 rows=12 width=133) (actual time=0.771..0.862 rows=12 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: ((sensor_lookup.sensorid)::text = (sensor.sensorid)::text)
   Buffers: shared hit=25
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.01..50.81 rows=12 width=119) (actual time=0.193..0.271 rows=12 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=19
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.60..26.10 rows=1 width=320) (actual time=0.163..0.228 rows=1 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=15
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.60..25.02 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.156..0.217 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=14
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.27..13.80 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.097..0.151 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=7
                           ->  Index Scan using meta_pkey on meta  (cost=0.27..4.29 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.029..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (stationid = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=3
                           ->  Seq Scan on meta_lookup  (cost=0.00..9.50 rows=1 width=31) (actual time=0.064..0.116 rows=1 loops=1)
                                 Filter: ((stationid)::bpchar = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 439
                                 Buffers: shared hit=4
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on datetime_lookup  (cost=2.33..11.21 rows=1 width=38) (actual time=0.054..0.060 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (stationid = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar)
                           Filter: ((productid)::text = 'qc60'::text)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                           Heap Blocks: exact=5
                           Buffers: shared hit=7
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_16  (cost=0.00..2.32 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=0.033..0.033 rows=6 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (stationid = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=2
               ->  Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=1 width=222) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((productid)::text = 'qc60'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                     Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using idx_15 on sensor_lookup  (cost=0.41..24.59 rows=12 width=30) (actual time=0.027..0.034 rows=12 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((stationid = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar) AND ((productid)::text = 'qc60'::text))
               Buffers: shared hit=4
   ->  Hash  (cost=10.68..10.68 rows=468 width=27) (actual time=0.547..0.548 rows=468 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 34kB
         Buffers: shared hit=6
         ->  Seq Scan on sensor  (cost=0.00..10.68 rows=468 width=27) (actual time=0.013..0.208 rows=468 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=6
 Planning time: 1.655 ms
 Execution time: 1.106 ms
```

Remote Planner:

```
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=26.67..102.51 rows=12 width=133) (actual time=0.644..0.719 rows=12 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: ((sensor_lookup.sensorid)::text = (sensor.sensorid)::text)
   Buffers: shared hit=29
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9.14..84.82 rows=12 width=119) (actual time=0.161..0.227 rows=12 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=19
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.60..38.12 rows=1 width=108) (actual time=0.128..0.187 rows=1 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=15
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.60..37.03 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.116..0.173 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=14
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.27..17.80 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.081..0.132 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=7
                           ->  Index Scan using meta_pkey on meta  (cost=0.27..8
.29 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (stationid = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=3
                           ->  Seq Scan on meta_lookup  (cost=0.00..9.50 rows=1 width=31) (actual time=0.067..0.117 rows=1 loops=1)
                                 Filter: ((stationid)::bpchar = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 439
                                 Buffers: shared hit=4
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on datetime_lookup  (cost=4.33..19.22 rows=1 width=38) (actual time=0.031..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (stationid = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar)
                           Filter: ((productid)::text = 'qc60'::text)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                           Heap Blocks: exact=5
                           Buffers: shared hit=7
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_16  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=6 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (stationid = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=2
               ->  Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((productid)::text = 'qc60'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                     Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on sensor_lookup  (cost=4.54..46.58 rows=12 width=30) (actual time=0.030..0.032 rows=12 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((stationid = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar) AND ((productid)::text = 'qc60'::text))
               Heap Blocks: exact=1
               Buffers: shared hit=4
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_15  (cost=0.00..4.54 rows=12 width=0) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=12 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((stationid = 'WYTOR02'::bpchar) AND ((productid)::text = 'qc60'::text))
                     Buffers: shared hit=3
   ->  Hash  (cost=11.68..11.68 rows=468 width=27) (actual time=0.440..0.440 rows=468 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 34kB
         Buffers: shared hit=7
         ->  Seq Scan on sensor  (cost=0.00..11.68 rows=468 width=27) (actual time=0.004..0.174 rows=468 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=7
 Planning time: 2.572 ms
 Execution time: 0.947 ms
```

Even though the difference is 1ms, these calls are done thousands of time so the difference adds up. The difference seems to ne that the reomote is doing a Bitmap Heap Scan as opposed to an Index Scan. Though I'm not sure these differences account for the planning time it is a difference between matching systems. The settings in the postgresql.conf are the same so what can I look at to see why these are different?

Both the local and remote servers have the same Postgresql and Ubuntu versions:
Ubuntu 18.04.1
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.15 (Ubuntu 10.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

Comment: Did you run `VACUUM ANALYZE` after the transfer? [ BTW: please don't post images; I cannot read them ]

Comment: I did after every INDEX I created. Sorry about the images, wasnt sure how else to show the planner differences

Comment: I cannot answer the question without the plans. Maybe the DB configuration is different? Or the content/distribution of the tables? WRT: query plans: just put `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` before your selects, and scrape the generated ASCII.

Comment: What I did was dump the DB from the remote and COPY it to the local system. I compared postgresql.conf file and they are the same so I'm stumped. Going to post the EXPLAIN ANALYZE JSON above.

Comment: The JSON format of the execution plan isn't really meant for humans to read. Please show us the plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`

Comment: On top of that, the JSON plan is malformed.

Comment: I see the execution time as being lower on the second (remote) one. Once you compile it into a stored procedure instead of running it as a query that planning time should go away. I'd say you've optimized this enough for now, looks like the remote is faster in execution time. And you said it runs 1000s of times, but in what timeframe, 1000 per minute or 1000 per day? 1ms extra 1000 times a day is 1 extra second execution a day, probably better things to work on, but if it runs 1000 times a minute maybe this is a worthy exercise.